# SOAP Webserice using Intellij-generated code, client certificate, and session cookies. Works stand-alone. Won't work in glassfish 3.1.2.2

Tags: java, ssl, cookies, intellij-idea, glassfish

I'm trying to call a 3rd party SOAP web service that we do not control.  This service is over https and requires both a client-side certificate, a user name and password, and a session cookie passed during one of many redirects done on the service side.

After much pain, I finally got this working in a stand-alone java application (using java 1.6) using the below code:

(note: TableOut, TableIn, DMService and DataManagementServicePortType were classes generated by IntelliJ from the WSDL)

```
public TableOut callWebService(TableIn tIn)throws Exception{
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", getKeyStoreLocationFile().getAbsolutePath());
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", getKeyStorePassword());
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", getTrustStoreLocationFile().getAbsolutePath());
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", getTrustStorePassword());

    Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(getServiceUserID(), getServicePassword().toCharArray());
        }
    });

    CookieManager manager = new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
    CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);

    DMService dmService = new DMService(new URL(getEndpointURL()), new QName("http://archserver.wsdl.dataflux.com", "DMService"));
    DataManagementServicePortType port = dmService.getPort(dmService.getServiceName(), DataManagementServicePortType.class);

    Map<String, Object> reqContext = ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext();

    reqContext.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, getEndpointURL());
    reqContext.put(BindingProvider.SESSION_MAINTAIN_PROPERTY, true);

    TableOut tOut = port.datasvcUidWsHcpDdfIn(tIn);
}
```

The call returns the desired results running in a main method.  However, the true usage of this web service call is in the context of a larger, existing web application.  The problem I'm having is it seems I'm not getting any cookies into the CookieManager when running on the application server.  In the app server I am not setting the system properties as glassfish has its own keystore and cacerts, which have had the client and server certificates added, respectively.  I'm learning all this stuff as I go so I'm pretty new to cookie handling, SSL certs and cookie handling in general.

I've written a small JSP test including the code above to make sure the larger application wasn't doing something to thwart my cookie retrieval and even then, no cookies in the CookieManager. I'm using glassfish 3.1.2.2 and java 1.6.

I'm completely out of ideas, so any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that either glassfish was not using the right keystore, or it was ignoring the client key in that keystore but this ended up being a certificate issue, not a cookie issue (I wasn't getting the cookie because I wasn't passing the cert).  I ended up loading the working keystore file specifically for this URL connection/SSL Context and using it that way and it works now.